# What are multidisciplinary sports?

Tags: international-sports, track-and-field, triathlon, biathlon

What are sports that provide more disciplines?

I know

- [triathlon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triathlon) (swimming + cycling + running)
- [biathlon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biathlon) (cross country skiing + shooting)
- [heptathlon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptathlon)/[decathlon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decathlon) (track and field)

are there any other?

I mean sports practiced in non-restricted areas of the world

Comment: I think this needs to be scoped a bit more narrowly to keep the number of answers to a resonable number: does [chess boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_boxing) count? Does [eventing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventing) count? If the answer to either of those is "no", why not? If the answer to both is "yes", there are going to be a *lot* of answers which are essentially "all round sport X" (all round gymnastics, combined downhill skiing, etc)

Comment: @PhilipKendall chess boxing seems ok (and also very interesting), eventing and all roud gymnastic it is not clear, while combined downhill skiing in my humble opinion is probably not (as medley for swimming)

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking" as you've just said yourself that there are no clear criteria for determining what would constitute a good answer.

Comment: @PhilipKendall in my opinion eventing, all around gymnastic and combined downhill skiing (as far as I read today) should not be included in this reply

Comment: I think that [Category:Combination events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Combination_events) at Wikipdia, together with some subcategories like [Category:Combined track and field event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Combined_track_and_field_events) or [Category:Multisports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Multisports) give (at least partial) answer to your question.

Comment: choker = chess + poker

Answer (score 4):

[Racketlon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racketlon) a combination of racket sports.

[Modern pentathlon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_pentathlon)  fencing, swimming, show jumping, shooting, running.

[Throws pentathlon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throws_pentathlon)

[Chess boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_boxing)

Also possibly: [Joggling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joggling) running/juggling, [Cycle ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_ball) cycling/football and [Underwater hockey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_hockey) hockey/swimming.

Comment: Also [biathlon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbptPx9dmC4).

Comment: @TRiG Biathlon is already mentioned in the question as example

Comment: choker = chess + poker